# How to split strings basing on spaces?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sample data like this

```
     DECLARE @Table1 table ([name] varchar(62));

     INSERT INTO @Table1
            ([name])
        VALUES
            ('2018-08-08 23:02:57,731 INFO  [AllRequestInterceptor] CRTST020'),
            ('2018-08-08 23:03:11,687 INFO  [SOAPLoggingHandler] CRTST020'),
            ('2018-08-08 23:03:02,028 ERROR [AJAXController] CRTST003');
```

I'm trying to create 4 columns based on the spaces provided.

```
     SELECT 
         Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse([name]), ' ', '.'), 1)) As [M1]
         ,Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse([name]), ' ', '.'), 2)) As [M2]
         ,Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse([name]), ' ', '.'), 3)) As [M3]
         ,Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse([name]), ' ', '.'), 4)) As [M4]

      FROM  (Select [name] from @Table1
      ) As [x]
```

Expected output  :

```
Date                    Name    Req                     Code
8/8/2018 23:02:57,731   INFO    [AllRequestInterceptor] CRTST020
8/8/2018 23:03:11,687   INFO    [SOAPLoggingHandler]    CRTST020
8/8/2018 23:03:02,028   ERROR   [AJAXController]        CRTST003
```

Comment: You have multiple spaces in your values, and some aren't delimiters (for example the space in `2018-08-08 23:02:57,731` in to a delimiter). This isn't fixed width either. You need to use a delimiter that doesn't appear in your data, or choose another method.

Comment: @Larnu even though data have spaces we should consider it as a whole one column and rest of all need to divide by spaces

Comment: Could `Req` have a space? What about `Code`? How do *you* know where one column starts if the things that identifies it starts may *not* mean it starts?

Comment: yes @Larnu all should be divided by space make an exception for date column space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
    DECLARE  @Table1 table ([name] varchar(1000));

    INSERT INTO @Table1
        ([name])
    VALUES
        ('2018-08-08 23:02:57,731 INFO [AllRequestInterceptor] CRTST020'),
        ('2018-08-08 23:03:11,687 INFO [SOAPLoggingHandler] CRTST020'),
        ('2018-08-08 23:03:02,028 ERROR [AJAXController] CRTST003');


    SELECT DISTINCT Split.a.value('/S[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')+' '+ Split.a.value('/S[2]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') [Date],
            Split.a.value('/S[3]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') As Name,
            Split.a.value('/S[4]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') As Req,
            Split.a.value('/S[5]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') As Code
    FROM
    (
        SELECT   CAST('<S>'+REPLACE([name] ,' ','</S><S>' ) +'</S>' AS XML) AS [name]
        FROM @Table1
    ) AS A
    CROSS APPLY [name].nodes('S') AS Split(a)
```

Result

```
Date                     Name   Req                     Code
----------------------------------------------------------------
2018-08-08 23:02:57,731  INFO   [AllRequestInterceptor] CRTST020
2018-08-08 23:03:02,028  ERROR  [AJAXController]        CRTST003
2018-08-08 23:03:11,687  INFO   [SOAPLoggingHandler]    CRTST020
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't ideal, but *assuming* that the only place a space will appear (other than as a delimiter) in the value of `date`, you could use  a string splitter and then pivot the data back. This uses [`delimitedsplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2), as ordinal position is important:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT T1.name,
           DS.ItemNumber,
           DS.Item,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.[name] ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber ASC) AS RN
    FROM @Table1 T1
         CROSS APPLY dbo.delimitedsplit8k_LEAD(T1.[name],' ') DS
    WHERE DS.Item <> '')
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Item END) + ' ' + MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Item END) AS [Date],
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN Item END) AS [Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 4 THEN Item END) AS Req,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 5 THEN Item END) AS Code
FROM CTE
GROUP BY [Name];
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7db7094c9cf825b56ffe1d33538c5d08)

Blarg, if you *can't* create the funciton, you *could* do thuis (but yuck):

```
DECLARE @Table1 table ([name] varchar(62));

INSERT INTO @Table1 ([name])
VALUES ('2018-08-08 23:02:57,731 INFO  [AllRequestInterceptor] CRTST020'),
       ('2018-08-08 23:03:11,687 INFO  [SOAPLoggingHandler] CRTST020'),
       ('2018-08-08 23:03:02,028 ERROR [AJAXController] CRTST003');

DECLARE @Delimiter char(1) = ' ';

WITH E1  (N) AS
    (SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1),     --10E+1 or 10 rows
E2  (N) AS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM E1 AS a,
          E1 AS b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
E4  (N) AS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM E2 AS a,
          E2 AS b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
cteTally (N) AS
    ( --==== This provides the "zero base" and limits the number of rows right up front
    -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
    SELECT 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 62
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4),
cteStart (N1, [name]) AS
    ( --==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
    SELECT t.N + 1,
           T1.[name]
    FROM cteTally AS t
         CROSS JOIN @Table1 AS T1
    WHERE (SUBSTRING(T1.[name], t.N, 1) = @Delimiter
        OR t.N = 0)),
Splits AS
    (SELECT s.[name],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.N1) AS ItemNumber,
            SUBSTRING(s.[name], s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF((LEAD(s.N1, 1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY s.[name] ORDER BY s.N1) - 1), 0) - s.N1, 8000)) AS item
     FROM cteStart AS s),
CTE AS
    (SELECT name,
            ItemNumber,
            item,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [name] ORDER BY ItemNumber ASC) AS RN
     FROM Splits
     WHERE item <> '')
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN item END) + ' ' + MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN item END) AS [Date],
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN item END) AS [Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 4 THEN item END) AS Req,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 5 THEN item END) AS Code
FROM CTE
GROUP BY [name];
```

Comment: thanks for answering I don't have permission to create dbo.delimitedsplit8k_LEAD function in my DB's

Comment: Well, considering that your data can't be normalised to be fixed width (as Gordan went down that route), you're going to really struggle. you'll likely have to write the code for `delimitedsplit8K_LEAD` in your SQL, rather than calling it as a function; far from ideal but neither is the data.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is almost a fixed-length format.  For your sample data, you can use string functions:

```
select left(name, 23) as date,
       trim(substring(name, 25, 6)) as name,
       trim(substring(name, 31, len(name) - 39)) as req,
       right(name, 8) as code
from @table1 t1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=127b6f268061322d2e6398b95b1f6647) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Gordon I have just posted sample records . We are not sure that we at going to get same length  every time

Answer (score 1):

You can use multi `apply` for this :

```
select substring(name, 0, n) as [Date], substring(d, 0, d1) as Name, substring(d, d1, d2-d1+1) as Req, substring(d, d2+1, len(name)) as Code
from @Table1 t1 cross apply
     ( values (patindex('%[a-z]%', name)) 
     ) tt(n) cross apply
     ( values (substring(name, n, len(name)))
     ) ttt(d) cross apply
     ( values (charindex('[', d), charindex(']', d)) 
     ) tttt(d1, d2);
```